# How can I compile PL/SQL source saved in table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I compile PL/SQL source code that I currently have saved in an Oracle table?  (I'm making a copy of the source code from the USER_SOURCE view, then I'm deleting those objects and want to restore from my saved copy.)

I'm sure there is an easy way, but I'm just not entering the right search terms.

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to do.  What are you trying to accomplish?  If it is backup/restore, use datapump.

Comment: Research about `dbms_sql` or/and `execute immediate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare
 text varchar2(4000);
begin
 select code into text from bkp_table;
 execute immediate 'create or replace ' || text;
end;
/
```

Ok this works if all lines of code are stored in single line. If you want to execute code that is stored in multiple lines you should go for something like:

```
declare 
  text varchar2(32767);
begin
  select listagg(text, ' ') within group (order by line) into text from all_source where name = 'MYPROC';
  execute immediate 'create or replace ' || text;
end;
/
```

Problem starts when 32767 characters is too few. In such case this may be a solution:

```
declare 
  text clob;
begin
for x in (select text from all_source where name = 'LONGTEST') loop
  text := text || x.text;
end loop;
  execute immediate 'create or replace ' || text;
end;
/
```

Please also have a look on [that](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1943344500346351703) why it is a bit odd thing.

**EDIT**

As suggested changed to `dbms_lob` and in that case `clob` needs to be initialised:

```
declare 
  text clob := ' ';
begin
for x in (select text from all_source where name = 'LONGTEST') loop
  dbms_lob.append(text, x.text);
end loop;
  execute immediate 'create or replace ' || text;
end;
/
```

Comment: A small observation, if you use "text := text || x.text;" you are going to run into "Shlemiel The Painter" algorithm issue, please use "dbms_lob.append(text, x.text);".

Comment: @alexs OK I added edited code. In that case also `clob` need to be initialised. When I changed only concatenation to packaged there was `ORA-06502`.